# Disabled Microsoft CI is still attempting to deploy

Tags: continuous-integration

About six months ago I contacted Microsoft support because when I did Continuous Delivery I would get error messages from every server it had once been on, that it failed.  (five or six messages each time)
Since it was not supposed to actually deploy to any of those servers that were no longer being used, I contacted Microsoft support.
They were unable to figure out the cause, despite an email chain to me that was at least 35 responses deep.
So, they disabled CI for my repository.
Not a great solution, but I no longer needed to worry about my code being deployed to random servers.
However, today, even though have not enabled CI configuration I again received a message that it had attempted to deploy and failed.
So, if Microsoft can't fix this CI issue, what is my next step?
EDIT:  Well, it looks like the one failed deployment was a fluke as I have since checked in twice more, and I havent received any emails indicated a failed deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I have since pushed a build twice more and it did not happen again. So random error I guess.